# How to exclude some extension files when copy a folder

Tags: linux, bash

I need copy folderA to folder_B, but I want exclude all *.xml when copy.

How can I use a linux cmd to implement the requirement in ternimal?

I was asked to find a different way than `cp -rf sourcedir/!(*.xml) dest_dir/`

Comment: Why do you have to find a different way? That's the best way to do it unless you need to be compatible with POSIX shell.

Comment: Use a `for` loop, and then an `if` statement to check that the suffix is not `.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to use `find` command:

```
 cp $(find sourcedir -type f -not -name "*.xml") dest_dir
```

Suggesting to try and tune the `find` command:

```
 find sourcedir -type f -not -name "*.xml"
```

Comment: This is susceptible to various bugs; please review https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020